# How does a completely offline wallet "registers" and runs

Tags: wallet, coldstorage, offline-transactions

A wallet which was made offline and will never ever see the internet how is it "registered" and runs in the blockchain. Is it through the watch-only wallet?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13225/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4239/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/23360/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/34078/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/80514/5406

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no wallet registration in the Bitcoin blockchain. The Bitcoin blockchain is a public ledger that records transactions and nothing more. Wallets are completely isolated components from that. The primary definition of wallets is that they represent a set of private keys. So if you were to write 10 private keys on a piece of paper, that could also be considered a wallet. Anything beyond that is just additional functionality developed by developers for end users to help them manage their keys, sign transactions, etc. more easily. Until the key from your wallet becomes part of the previously mentioned public ledger (blockchain), no one in the world knows of its existence.

Comment: And how excatly is an offline wallet mentioned in the public ledger.

Comment: @Papi Wallets are not part of the public ledger (blockchain). Therefore, they are not mentioned in any way regardless of whether they are "online" or "offline".